# Instant messaging Tuleap

Tags: openfire, tuleap

I would like to find out the state of Instant messaging on Tuleap projects using openfire & Muckl Does it work at all?

If it is then:

I have configured openfire, once the project is created the room for instant messaging is created in openfire and everything else seems to be working fine on that side apart from when you go to project board and try to run "instant messaging" it shows message "service Unavailable". Is muckl compatible with latest browsers there is very little documentation or explanation on this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't support well web MUC AFAIR.

Did you try to connect with a 3rd party jabber client ?

Comment: I havent but what im looking for is project integration in to chat for project groups, and relevant info to the project what MUCK have had provided. So any solutions ideas or simillar 3rd party chats that can do something like that.

Comment: At least trying with a 3rd party client would help to know if it's a server issue or a web client issue.